# Java android sync project gradle build fail:Error:(42) No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'

Tags: java

When I build project I see in messages :

```
C:\Users\022\Desktop\PairingCodes\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(42) No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'
```

and this is on color red:

```
 android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```